# Am I right to call multiple asynchronous methods in a row?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

During startup, the application I need to get two sets of data, each has its asynchronous method. If I call them one by one, then the second call will pass only after completion of the first.

```
List<DataOne> DataCollectionOne;
List<DataTwo> DataCollectionTwo;

async void GetDatas()
    {
      if(sameCondOne)
        DataCollectionOne = await GetDataOne();
      if(sameCondTwo)
        DataCollectionTwo = await GetDataTwo();
    }
```

So I wrapped them in the task calls.

```
void GetDatas()
    {
      if(sameCondOne)
        Task.Run(() => RunDataOne());
      if(sameCondTwo)
        Task.Run(() => RunDataTwo());
    }

async void RunDataOne()
    {
      DataCollectionOne = await GetDataOne();
    }

async void RunDataTwo()
    {
      DataCollectionTwo = await GetDataTwo();
    }
```

I am doing right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you should avoid void returning `async` methods ([Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)).

It is a common practice to suffix `async` methods with **Async** (or **TaskAsync** if **Async** suffixed methods already exist).

If I understand you correctly, you want to spawn some conditional asynchronous interdependent tasks and wait for  all the tasks to end without having any of them wait for another.

Since you are doing anything with the result of the tasks in the orchestrating method but you need istead some side effects, I would wrap the **Get~** methods into **Run~**  methods like you did.

You could test the condition inside the **Run~** methods (either by explicitly testing the condition or having it as a parameter):

```
async Task RunDataOneAsymc()
{
    if (sameCondOne)
    {
        DataCollectionOne = await GetDataOneAsync();
    }
}
```

But this would still spawn unnecessary tasks if the condition is false. So, it's better to keep it on the caller side:

```
async Task RunDataOneAsymc()
{
    DataCollectionOne = await GetDataOneAsync();
}

// ...
if (sameCondOne)
{
    await RunDataOneAsymc();
}
```

On the orchestating method, you will spawn the tasks if the condition is true and then wait for all of them to complete:

```
async Task RunAll()
{
    var tasks = new List<Task>();

    if (sameCondOne)
    {
        await RunDataOneAsymc();
    }

    // ...

    if (sameCondN)
    {
        await RunDataNAsymc();
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

Answer (score 10):

No.  You don't need, nor want to spin up a new thread just to be responsible for *starting* these two asynchronous operations.  Simply start both operations (calling the method is what starts the operation) and don't await either until you've started them both:

```
var firstTask = GetDataOne();
var secondTask = GetDataTwo();

var firstResult = await firstTask;
var secondResult = await secondTask;
```

To handle the conditional check just conditionally start the task, and then conditionally assign the result:

```
Task<T> firstTask = null;
if(shouldGetFirstTask)
    firstTask = GetDataOne();
Task<T> secondTask = null;
if(shouldGetSecondTask)
    secondTask = GetDataTwo();

if(firstTask != null)
    DataCollectionOne = await firstTask;
if(secondTask != null)
    DataCollectionTwo = await secondTask;
```

Comment: Thank you. The second option works if the same tasks. I have a different tasks. 
And second, the collection filled by some condition. 
I'm a little to fix the issue.